# Do degenerate states have exchange energy?

Tags: resonance, atomic-structure

I have read that exchange energy exists between non-degenerate levels $1s$ and $2s$ or between $1s$ and $2p_x$ in the Helium atom in the first excited level:
$$K_s = \left< 1s(1)2s(2)|H'|1s(2)2s(1) \right>
$$
$$K_p = \left< 1s(1)2p_x(2)|H'|1s(2)2p_x(1) \right>
$$
What about the exchange between $2p_x$ and $2p_y$ in the next excited level? Is $$  \left< 2p_x(1)2p_y(2)|H'|2p_x(2)2p_y(1) \right> =0$$? Here, $$H'= \frac {e^2}{r_{12}} $$ is perturbation term. Thanks.

Comment: Short answer is yes, there are exchange energies among degenerate orbitals. Most often discussed with respect to d orbitals, probably because of stable transition metals with multiple unpaired electrons in d orbitals